# How can I reproduce “Leap Second Bug” on my linux system

Tags: linux, futex

I'm using java application on linux system(Redhat 6.6). Some times this application charged CPU 100%.

**This is proc strace.**

```
[chgminer@perpscm CE]$ strace -p 18182
...
sched_yield()                           = 0
sched_yield()                           = 0
futex(0x7ff5ec021e54, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {16502241, 759149277}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
futex(0x7ff5ec021e28, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
...
```

`strace` printed `"futex .. ETIMEOUT"`. So I guess "Leap Second Bug".

And I want to fix this problem. 
But the problem machine can not access some reason.

So I must reproduce this situation on other system(linux).

How can I reproduce this situation?

**System Infomation**

- OS : Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 (amd64)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I reproduce "Leap Second Bug" on my linux system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44362726/how-can-i-reproduce-leap-second-bug-on-my-linux-system)

Comment: Why do you think it's a leap second bug that's causing this?

Comment: Also see [Resolve Leap Second Issues in Red Hat Enterprise Linux](https://access.redhat.com/articles/15145). According to Red Hat's article, *"At this time, we are not aware of upcoming leap second events"*. So it appears there have been no events recently to affect your software. Maybe something else is the problem???